# Responding to client with error "An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command"

Tags: appium

Can anyone explain what is the error in this????

Responding to client with error: {"status":13,"value":{"message":"An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.","origValue":"Coordinate [x=800.0, y=619.0] is outside of element rect: [0,0][800,1205]"},"sessionId":"d19ce74a-bc57-4b86-bac4-0a63c9471c0b"}

> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/d19ce74a-bc57-4b86-bac4-0a63c9471c0b/touch/perform 500 16.024 ms - 242
>
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Display bounds: [0,0][800,1205]
>
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":13,"value":"Coordinate [x=800.0, y=619.0] is outside of element rect: [0,0][800,1205]"}

Comment: Which action you are doing ? e.g swipe

Comment: Post your code and error log.